# Are there any shorter keyword rather than using \textsubscript or \textsuperscript in TexStudio?

Tags: macros

Are there any shorter keyword rather than using `\textsubscript` or `\textsuperscript` in TexStudio ?

Usually I use these two keyword to make a sub-/super-script in presentation. I found that even I tried `\texttt{example\_example}` or `\verb|example\_example}|`, both of these commands gave me an error and strange output as well.

Then I switch to use the kind of `\textsubscript` instead, it works well but very consuming the time.

So can I ask you guys for the another way that faster than using such of above those keywords ?

THX in adv.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you explain in which context you need these two commands? Usually there should be no need to use them frequently; and in math mode you have `_` and `^`.

Comment: @gernot I already tried these symbols, says, text_{text}, but unluckily TexStudio gave me an error every time of compiling. Btw, I do not sure that if I do need to change the program setting or not?

Comment: @gernot This text is some of error that I got.

Missing $ inserted. \end{frame}
Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{frame}
Missing $ inserted. \end{frame}

Comment: Please add the code of a short document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) to your question  that illustrates your problem. Use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/339061/edit) left below of your posting.

Comment: Thx so much. @gernot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`texstudio` is completely unrelated to this question, it is just the editor you used to type the tex source. You would get the identical behaviour if you used `notepad` or `emacs` or even `vim`.

The behaviour is coming from latex. As with any command, you can define your own names. If you define

```
\newcommand\SB[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
```

then you can use `\SB{text}` instead of `\textsubscript{text}`